# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE for both space and "%" at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have following Oracle SQL code:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(per_growth, '(%)(\s)')),
                 'FM99999999999999999990D099999999999999999',
                 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', ''') AS per_growth
  FROM sometable;
```

This code supposed to look for percentage sign first then space and exclude them from the result. However, it is showing

> **ORA-01722**: invalid number

error. I am learning sql yet and do not know exact cause. Is it something went wrong with `(%)(\s)`? The value in the table is 50%

Comment: Could you please check if the problem relates to the column "per_growth"? When you try such a select, is this failing, too? select '50 % ', to_number(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('50 % ', '(%)(\s)')),'FM99999999999999999990D099999999999999999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', ''') as test from dual;

Comment: it is working for me. It seems i have error with the parameter!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRANSLATE` to get rid of all instances of unwanted characters:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         TRANSLATE(per_growth, '0% ', '0'),
         'FM99999999999999999990D099999999999999999',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', '''
       ) as per_growth
FROM   sometable;
```

*Note: `TRANSLATE(expr, from_string, to_string)` works by swapping all instances of the characters in `from_string` with the corresponding characters in `to_string` and if there are more characters in `from_string` than `to_string` then the remaining characters are removed. It is faster than using regular expressions and on a par with using `REPLACE` but it can handle multiple replacements at once, which `REPLACE` cannot.*

If you did want to use the slower `REGEXP_REPLACE` then you can replace all whitespace characters and all percent characters, whether together or not, using:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(per_growth, '[%[:space:]]'),
         'FM99999999999999999990D099999999999999999',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', '''
       ) as per_growth
FROM   sometable;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sometable (per_growth) AS
SELECT '1%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '%2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3 %' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4% ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5,0%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '%%% 123 456 789,0123456 %' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | PER_GROWTH |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |
> | 4 |
> | 5 |
> | 123456789.0123456 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3b5f1cee3d5238cfab0385c395d46e09)*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try good, old `REPLACE`?

```
select replace(replace(per_growth, '%', ''), ' ', '') as result
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(per_growth, '( )(%)')
```

in order to get rid of `%` sign and `whitespace(s)` together

**or**

```sql
TRIM(REPLACE(per_growth,'%'))
```

to get rid of `%` sign first, and then `leading` and `trailing` spaces next,

before numerical conversion.